# how to get crtime of a file in an ext4 partition as a single number or string

Tags: bash, filesystems, ext4, timestamps

I am seeking a method of getting the crtime of a file in hexadecimal or decimal in unix epoch seconds instead of in a date and clock format and with no additional output.

This command adds **additional text** at the top of the output ( such as "debugfs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)") that's impossible to remove with grep, sed, etc.

```
debugfs -R 'stat <7473635>' /dev/sda7 | grep ctime
```

This command gives the **modification** time in unix epoch seconds.

```
date -r default.txt +%s
```

Additionally all the other posts I've looked at that do get crtime of files get it in a date and clock opposed to unix epoch time. In conclusion how do I get only the creation time of a file in an ext4 fs in unix epoch seconds.

Comment: If you have a method that gets it in an unambiguous calendar output (e.g. `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` or similar), `date` can convert it to epoch time for you (using `date -d "<calendar date>" +%s` or so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep` with PCRE (`-P`) to extract the desired portion and use it as input for `date`:

```
date --date="$(sudo debugfs .... |& grep -Po '^crtime.*-\s\K.*$')" '+%s'
```

Or

```
date --date="$(sudo debugfs .... 2>/dev/null | grep -Po '^crtime.*-\s\K.*$')" '+%s'
```

For example:

```
$ date --date="$(sudo debugfs -R 'stat <677051>' /dev/sda3 |& grep -Po '^crtime.*-\s\K.*$')" '+%s'
1442488264
```

---

You can also use `sed`:

```
date --date="$(sudo debugfs .... |& sed -n 's/^crtime.*- \(.*\)$/\1/p')" '+%s'
```

Or

```
date --date="$(sudo debugfs .... 2>/dev/null | sed -n 's/^crtime.*- \(.*\)$/\1/p')" '+%s'
```

For example:

```
$ date --date="$(sudo debugfs -R 'stat <677051>' /dev/sda3 |& sed -n 's/^crtime.*- \(.*\)$/\1/p')" '+%s'
1442488264
```